# Chrome (on Android) address dar doesn't dissapear while scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

For the current version of chrome on Android, when one scrolls down, the address bar auto-hides, making the website full screen. Here's an example:

[image]

So when I open SO, this^ is what I see.

[image]

Then when I scroll down^, the address bar disappears, as it should (happens for all websites I have seen so far).
But, for this specific website I've designed, such is not the case:

[image]

The address bar sticks on top, no matter what.
The link to the website is http://planetkde.org

The website is designed using Bootstrap v3.1. Has anyone faced a similar trouble before? Or is there a specific reason why this might be happening?

Edit: This issue doesn't occur in Firefox for Android (the address bar hides as it is supposed to), just chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791705/hide-mobile-browser-address-bar-on-chrome-android

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for. In general, shouldn't the address bar hide by itself? It happens for all the sites, even those that don't use JS at all. It's enabled by default in Chrome on Android these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visiting your site immediately showed the problem. And you should have seen it yourself because its on your screenshot :)

Your site is hosted over `https` but is loading mixed content from `http://ovidiu.geekaliens.com/` which is seen as a security warning. The browsers shows this warning in front of the URL in the browser-bar and therefore will not hide automatically.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that. It seems that it isn't a bug, it's a feature in that case. Thank you!